# Recommended font size for data intense Interfaces

Tags: business-application, font-sizes

I was wondering if there is any recommendation in font size for data intense interfaces? Users who use interfaces for several hours a day and are experts in using those interfaces might have other needs than the 16pt recommended by W3C?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

Ease of reading is not just based on font size, but also line spacing and text density. Also, it depends on the ratio of text to numbers and many other factors. I think 16pt isn't necessarily a recommendation but a starting point. You have to think of font size as one factor to balance in order to achieve optimal readability.

If you can reduce the amount of data or make it easier to visually process for the user, it generally will have a higher impact than increasing font size alone.